# Setting up Apache for Rails production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, deployment

I am developing a Rails 3 application and I have installed Capistrano on the client side and Passenger with Apache 2 on the server side.

I make a deployment and the files are sent to a folder called `u/apps/`.

But when I visit the IP address I am currently using I only get to an empty folder, how do I configure Apache to look for my app in the current folder? So that I only need to visit my IP/domain to see my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done this using Rails 2.x but I think for Rails 3 also pretty much the same thing. For this you need to use Passenger and then configure Apache.

Following are some useful resources

http://www.modrails.com/install.html

http://railscasts.com/episodes/122-passenger-in-development

Comment: Unfortunately its the apache setup that I cannot do. I do not know how to do it to get my deployed site to run. Do you have any tips?

Answer (score 0):

If you browse to your URL and you see an apache files/folders list that means that passenger is not triggered for that location...
Test your server environment by running a mongrel/thin in your application folder and see that your application runs correctly. After that, look at your Apache configuration (see Passenger docs).